# C: Error compiling - "expected expression" and nothing else written?

Tags: c, function, pointers, compiler-errors

I am writing the following program in C.

```
int xyz(char* x, char* y)
{
    [CODE HERE]
}

int ijk(char *i)
{
    return xyz(char* x, char* y);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
error: expected expression
    return xyz(char* x, char* y);
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Any idea on what the error might be? I have already checked for hidden characters.

Thanks!

Comment: You've already told xyz() what kinds of arguments to expect, so when you call the function you just pass them: `xyz(x, y)`. Of course, I don't see anywhere `x` and `y` are defined, so that's your next problem.

Comment: Kernighan & Ritchie have the solution to your problem. Read their great book and Bob should be your uncle.

Comment: You might want to learn C properly. You have tried something without understanding everything that's needed.

Answer (score 3):

When you call a function, you need to provide just the arguments, not the type.

instead of

```
return xyz(char* x, char* y);
```

use

```
return xyz(i, i);
```

or something along the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to return a function (as it appears you are from your tags) you need to return a reference to the function.

First, define a function pointer type:
`typedef int (*funcPointer)(char *, char *);`

Then the rest of your code:

```
int xyz(char* x, char* y)
{
    [CODE HERE]
}

funcPointer ijk(char *i)
{
    return &xyz; // Return a pointer to the function
}
```

Then you can do something like:
`ijk("b")("a", "b");`

Not sure exactly what your example is and if this is truly something you want to do. Not everything you learn in a functional world will translate well to C or other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value.

```
char* x = "Hello";
char* y = "World";

return xyz(x,y);
```